# Scala - why fail to override superclass's method

Tags: scala

```
  class A
  class B extends A

  class D { def get: A = ??? }
  class E extends D { override def get: B = ??? } // OK

  class F { def set(b: B): Unit = ??? }
  class G extends F { override def set(a: A): Unit = ??? } // Compile Error, override nothing
```

my question is why G doesn't work given that:
    (A=>Unit) is subtype of (B=>Unit)

```
implicitly[(A => Unit) <:< (B => Unit)]
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason is simple: the JVM doesn't allow overrides based on contravariance over parameter types. It only allows overrides based on covariance of return type.

Take a look [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7468.html) for some discussion about the implications of that on Scala.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Contravariant_method_argument_type):

> Similarly, it is type safe to allow an overriding method to accept a more general argument than the method in the base class:
>
> Ex:
>
> ```
> class AnimalShelter {
>     void putAnimal(Animal animal) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
>
> class CatShelter extends AnimalShelter {
>     void putAnimal(Object animal) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Not many object oriented languages actually allow this — **C++ and Java [and also Scala] would interpret this as an unrelated method with an overloaded name**.